# SSL error prevents website login in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Hay,

as a replacement for Xamarin I tried to create a app with the same functions in flutter. 
But the webview plugin/package doens't work with the self signed ssl certificate.
In Xamarin there was a way to handle the ssl errors and still
get the website loaded.

Current code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
    flutterWebviewPlugin.onHttpError.skip(1000);
    flutterWebviewPlugin.launch("https url to website", hidden: true,
        allowFileURLs: true,
        appCacheEnabled: true,
        withJavascript: true,
        withLocalStorage: true,
        withZoom: true);

flutterWebviewPlugin.onHttpError.skip(1000);
flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged((state) async)
{
  flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(
      "document.getElementById(\"name\").innerText = \"username\"");
  flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(
      "document.getElementById(\"password\").innerText = \"pw\"");
  flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(
      "document.getElementById(\"loginbutton\").invokeMember(\"click\")");
  var test = flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(
      "document.getElementById(\"errorbox\").innerText");
};
flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
flutterWebviewPlugin.close();
```

Error:

```
Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Is there a better way then writing an own package or an custom webview in java and swift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Android you could modify the plugin. Clone a copy to your local machine and add an additional override to `flutter_webview_plugin/android/src/main/java/com/flutter_webview_plugin/BrowserClient.java`

Override `public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, 
                SslErrorHandler handler, 
                SslError error)`
with an implementation that simply does `handler.proceed()`

Let's say your project is in `/projects/myproject` and you cloned the plugin into `/projects/flutter_webview_plugin`. Make the change in `/projects/flutter_webview_plugin/android/src/.../BrowserClient.java`. Then update the `pubspec.yaml` of your project with (replaces the existing entry for flutter_webview_plugin):

```
dependencies:
  flutter_webview_plugin:
    path: ../flutter_webview_plugin
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I will add a functions to ios and everything should work fine.

Comment: I added the line to the BrowserClient and moved the plugin to my lib folder and then the MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method launch on channel flutter_webview_plugin) pops up when using launch or stop.

Comment: You don't copy that file into your project - it stays in your copy of the plugin - which you reference through pubspec - see edits.

Comment: I added everything and the package works.
But still I got Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. and the page at *url* was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.", source: *url* (0)

Comment: Even with Mixed_Content_Always_Allow this pops up and the onStateChanged    Listener gives no message. Mixed Content: The page at *url* was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.", source: *url*/ (0)
*url* ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Does your onReceivedSslError callback get called? Can you also change the source of the page you are loading to fetch jQuery using https?

Comment: On the second click the ssl error disappears and only the jQuery error is there. I will remove jsquety when I'm back in the office.

Answer (score 0):

Today flutter_webview_plugin has a parameter `ignoreSSLErrors`. Example:

```
    return WebviewScaffold(
      url: url,
      ignoreSSLErrors: true,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
    );
```