# Zoom in Flutter with flutter_inappwebview

Tags: flutter, webview, package, zooming

I use the Code from one answer [webview_flutter "Failed to validate the certificate chain" SSL handshake failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253385/webview-flutter-failed-to-validate-the-certificate-chain-ssl-handshake-failed)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
 runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
       home: InAppWebViewPage()
   );
 }
} 

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
 InAppWebViewController webView;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("InAppWebView")
       ),
       body: Container(
           child: Column(children: <Widget>[
             Expanded(
               child: Container(
                 child: InAppWebView(
                   initialUrl: "https://myUrl",
                   initialHeaders: {},
                   initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                       inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                         debuggingEnabled: true,
                       ),
                   ),
                   onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                     webView = controller;
                   },
                   onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                   },
                   onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                   },
                   onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller, ServerTrustChallenge challenge) async {
                     return ServerTrustAuthResponse(action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
                   },
                 ),
               ),
             ),
           ]))
   );
 }
}
```

I tried to use the function to zoom, but flutter doens´t know the option. How can I add it to this function? I need these function for Android and iOS.

Comment: Try using `builtInZoomControls `, `displayZoomControls ` and `supportZoom `.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding different zoom options in InAppWebView as shown below?

```
child: InAppWebView(
  initialUrl: "https://myUrl",
  initialHeaders: {},
  initialOptions: ....
  displayZoomControls: true,
  supportZoom: true
```

You can learn more about these options at plugin's GitHub location - https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested it, but I get this error: "The named parameter 'displayZoomControls' isn't defined." "The named parameter 'supportZoom' isn't defined."

Comment: @miwa, that's odd. What version of `InAppWebView` do you have in your `pubspec.yaml`. Make sure you have `flutter_inappwebview: ^2.1.0+1`.

Comment: I use this package: flutter_inappbrowser: ^2.0.2
I tried to use your package but I cannot load it, I get an error.

Comment: is it necessary to implement androidx to my project to use the methods you told me to use?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) you can use **`builtInZoomControls` and `displayZoomControls`**,

> builtInZoomControls: Set to true if the WebView should use its built-in zoom mechanisms. The default value is false.
>
> ---
>
> displayZoomControls: Set to true if the WebView should display on-screen zoom controls when using the built-in zoom mechanisms. The default value is false.

```
InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                            inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                              initialUrl: "https://myUrl",
                              builtInZoomControls: true,
                              displayZoomControls: true,
                            ))));
```

**Note: You don't have to use `supportZoom` because it is `true` by default.**

> supportZoom: Set to false if the WebView should not support zooming using its on-screen zoom controls and gestures. The default value is true.